# Display By month using select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by

```
SELECT SUM(Total_A ) FROM Materials_List
```

This is the snippet of code that I have.

I need it to calculate by month and display by month using SQL.

I also would like it to be a code I can use for any month in the year not just one month at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for simple aggregation:

```
select
    year(materials_datetime) yr,
    month(materials_datetime) mn,
    sum(total_a) sum_total_a
from materials_list
group by
    year(materials_datetime),
    month(materials_datetime)
order by yr, mn
```

This assumes that column `materials_datetime` contains the date/time that you want to use to aggregate the data.

Comment: I need it ordered by the field [@ field:Date]

Comment: @AnthonyEdmondson: this query orders results by increasing year/month (so it is chronological). Give it a try against your dataset.

Comment: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: that's what I got from my datasheet in response to that particular string it did not work correctly honestly.

Comment: SELECT
    sum(total_a) 
FROM materials_list
GROUP BY
    year(Date),
    month(Date)
ORDER  BY 
   Month(Current_Month)

Comment: It almost works that way but the last column gives me an error for some reason

Comment: @AnthonyEdmondson: `Month(Current_Month)` is not part of the `group by` clause so you cannot use it in the `order by` clause. Please run the query exactly as provided.